# Erro PHP com SQLserver exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Instalei o driver certinho no PHP, adicionei a extensão no `php.ini`, mas quando tento conectar com PDO no sqlserver, aparece este erro:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Provedor de Pipes Nomeados:
>   não foi possível abrir uma conexão com SQL Server.

Eu não sei mais o que pode ser, estou usando a versão 5.5 do PHP e o banco SQLserver express 2014. Segue meu código de conexão com o banco de dados:

```
    $UserName = 'sa';
    $Password = 'xxxxx';

try{
    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=banco", "$UserName", "$Password");
 echo "banco conectado OK!";
}catch (PDOException $exception)
{
  die("Não é possível se conectar ao banco de dados.<br />Error message:<br /><br />$exception.");
}
```

É a primeira vez que tento conectar PHP com SQLserver. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço :)

Comment: Qual a porta do seu SQLSERVER?

Comment: a password *xxxxx* é proposital?

Comment: A porta é a 1234... A senha coloquei 'xxxxx' apenas proposital, só para a pergunta mesmo ;)

Comment: tente colocar a porta

Comment: @stderr muito bem observado.

Comment: o erro continua?

Comment: Opa, realmente as variaveis estavam erradas, mas mesmo corrigindo, ou até mesmo colocando user e senha direto, o erro persiste, ja coloquei a porta tbm e nada... :/

Comment: o nome do banco é banco?

Comment: Assim como a senha, o nome do banco foi proposital na pergunta... ;) ésta é a extensão que adicionei no php.ini... extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu trabalho com mysql fazendo updates de um banco de dados MsSql. E já usei conexões com ACCESS tbm.

Para os dois uso conexão odbc.

```
$db = odbc_connect( $connect_string,$user, $password );
```

Igual ao sugerido pela [documentação oficial do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php).

Nota: Faça um `phinfo()` para ter certeza que o seu drive está ativo.

Em seguida cheque [credenciais de acesso ao MSSQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/195566).

Comment: Galera!!! Consegui, assim como o **zwitterion** falou!! Usei conexão via ODBC, e não da forma que eu estava fazendo. A conexão funfou certinho, fiz até um select via PHP pra ver se estava realmente certo, e funfou corretamente! o script ficou assim: `$con = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=banco; Uid=sa;Pwd=xxxxx;"); `  Obrigado pela ajuda de todos, cada comentário foi extremamente útil para mim! Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver correto conforme o seu comentário, você disse que a porta é `1234`, então deve ser algo customizado, porque a porta padrão do SQLServer é `1433`, para acessar uma porta diferente você deve adicionar uma virgula após o hostname e em seguida a porta que esta usando:

```
$con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=[HOST],[PORTA];Database=[BANCO]", "$UserName", "$Password");
```

Seria algo como:

```
$con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost,1234;Database=banco", "$UserName", "$Password");
```

Tal como os exemplos da documentação http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php#example-1097